# Communication between two fragments (android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Screen of my app is divided into two fragments ( upper and lower ). Upper fragment is a question(`QuizFragmentType1`) and lower fragment (`QuizFragment`) is containing a button "next" which is changing the upper fragment.

How can I get data from upper fragment by pressing the button "next" in the lower fragment?

The problem is in the method `checkAnswers()`. When I try to get some data from `QuizFragmentType1` I can't. For example:

```
RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

`radioGroup1` is in the layout of `QuizFragmentType1` so I can't reach it.
I am obviously missing some communication between these two fragments.

Any suggestions?

This is the code:

Lower Fragment (QuizFragment.java)

```
public class QuizFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

List<Question> quesList;
Button butNext;
EditText input_answer;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
private GameActivity activity;
int i = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    butNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    butNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 1;
    int High = 3;
    int numb = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

    if (numb == 1) {
        ((GameActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(R.id.game,
                new QuizFragmentType1());
    } else if (numb == 2) {
        ((GameActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(R.id.game,
                new QuizFragmentType2());
    }
}

public void randomQuestionType() {
    if (i < 5) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 1;
        int High = 3;
        int numb = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

        if (numb == 1) {
            ((GameActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(R.id.game,
                    new QuizFragmentType1());
        } else if (numb == 2) {
            ((GameActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(R.id.game,
                    new QuizFragmentType2());
        }
        i++;
    }
    else {
        ((GameActivity) getActivity()).setupFragment(R.id.game,
                new ResultFragment());
    }

}

public void checkAnswers() {
    RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(
            grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    String input = ((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.userInput))
            .getText().toString();

    if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(answer.getText())) {
        score++;
        Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);

    } else if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(input)) {
        score++;
        Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
        input_answer.getText().clear();
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    randomQuestionType();
}
```

}

Upper Fragment (QuizFragmentType1.java) or (QuizFragmentType2.java)

```
public class QuizFragmentType1 extends BaseFragment implements SetQuestionView {

static List<Question> quesList;
int qid = 0;
static Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;

float help = 0;
private GameActivity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (this.activity == null)
        this.activity = (GameActivity) activity;
    quesList = Question.getQuestions(this.activity.getCurrentCategory());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz_type1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Random br = new Random();
    currentQ = quesList.get(br.nextInt(quesList.size()));

    txtQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

    setQuestionView();

    for (int i = 0; i < quesList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("Debug", "Pitanje " + i + ": "
                + quesList.get(i).getQuestion());
    }
}
public void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQuestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOptA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOptB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOptC());
    qid++;
}
```

}

Comment: Try using callbacks with the activity that create the fragments

Comment: You mean I should use an interface?

Comment: yes, i think this is a good approach, or use a event bus to send event between fragments

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do is create a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), a class which can handle communication (interact) for all of your app's components, i.e. activity, fragment, service, etc. Once your `Fragment` already registered `LocalBroadcastManager`, it can communicate with your custom `IntentFilter`. You don't need to register it in the manifest, just register it in the class you need to receive the information from other components.

From the sender class, call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
intent.putExtra("key", dataToBePassed);// may boolean, String, int, etc.
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

From the receiver, register it inside `onCreate()` method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
```

Also, make sure that you need to unregister it inside `onDestroy()` method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
```

Get the information from the receiver Fragment class:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
      }
    };
```

Note: change `context` with `getActivity()` if you register it on `Fragment`. If on `Activity`, change with `this`.

For more example, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/3922207).